# Retrieve Custom Label from Salesforce to Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, customlabel, label

Does anybody know the way to retrieve the value of a Custom Label from Salesforce to Marketing cloud using either SSJS or AMPscript?

Comment: What have you tried so far? In what context do you plan to use it?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure where in SFMC you're trying to run that code, but it won't work.

There are two ways to retrieve Salesforce data in Marketing Cloud:

1. Use Synchronized Data Sources to synch the object that has this custom label and use either SSJS or AMPscript to pull the values from the Synchronized Data Extensions. Downside: Synchronized Data Sources can be refreshed at max. 15-minute interval, so you might not always get the latest data. More info: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_creating_and_interacting_with_synchronized_data_sources.htm&type=5

Example:

```js
%%[
SET @LeadId = _subscriberkey
IF NOT EMPTY(@LeadId) THEN
  SET @email = LOOKUP("ent.Lead_Salesforce","Email","Id",@LeadId)
ENDIF
]%%
Your email: %%=v(@email)=%%
```

2. You can pull Salesforce data into the code in real-time directly using the AMPscript Sales and Service Cloud function RetrieveSalesforceObjects: https://ampscript.guide/retrievesalesforceobjects/

Here's an example from the [ampscript.guide](https://ampscript.guide/):

The following example retrieves a record from the Sales Cloud Contact object and displays values on a page for a matching record Id.

```js
%%[

var @subscriberRows

set @subscriberRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
   "Contact",
   "FirstName,LastName,Email",
   "Id", "=", _subscriberKey )

if RowCount(@subscriberRows) == 1 then /* there should only be one row */
  var @subscriberRow, @firstName, @lastName, @email
  set @subscriberRow = Row(@subscriberRows, 1)
  set @firstName = Field(@subscriberRow, "FirstName")
  set @lastName = Field(@subscriberRow, "LastName")
  set @email = Field(@subscriberRow, "Email")
endif

]%%
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <h2>Your Details</h2>

      %%[ if RowCount(@subscriberRows) == 1 then ]%%
      <ul>
         <li><strong>First Name:</strong> %%=v(@firstName)=%%</li>
         <li><strong>Last Name:</strong> %%=v(@lastName)=%%</li>
         <li><strong>Email:</strong> %%=v(@email)=%%</li>
      </ul>
      %%[ else ]%%
      <p>You are not registered.</p>
      %%[ endif ]%%
   </body>
</html>
```

Don't use option #2 in emails and for bulk operations.

If needed, you can pass variable values between AMPscript and SSJS: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_utilitiesVariableGetValue.htm

Comment: Thank you, I know how to retrieve objects from Salesforce. 
But the issue is about custom labels. Do you know how to get values from labels on Salesforce and use it on Marketing Cloud?

Comment: Not possible by default. As a workaround you could create an object in Salesforce and create the labels you need as records.